# "Dynamic" Java Code

Tags: java

I don't know if the title is correct, but what I want to do is to write a method that adds for example the rgb of a color to a combobox. Let's assume that we have 3 panels each one with different background color and each panel has its own combo box.

```
int p1RGB = (Panel1.getBackground()).getRGB();
    int p1Red = (p1RGB>>16)&0xFF;
    int p1Green = (p1RGB>>8)&0xFF;
    int p1Blue = p1RGB&0xFF;
    String p1RGBStr = String.valueOf(p1Red) +", "+String.valueOf(p1Green) +", "+ String.valueOf(p1Blue); 
    String[] c1Items = { hex1, p1RGBStr };
    DefaultComboBoxModel model1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel (c1Items);
    Combo1.setModel(model1);
```

Instead writing again this code for each panel can I write this in a way that it loops itself for each panel? I think there is something similar in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's assume that we have 3 panels each one with different background color and each panel has its own combo box.

You have a model: Panel + combo.

I would create custom class inherited from `JPanel` and create list of models. It will make code clearer.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{/* */}
```

*MainClass*

```
List<MyPanel> listOfPanels = new ArrayList<MyPanel>(3);

for(MyPanel model : listOfPanels ){
  doStuff(model);
} 

private void doStuff(MyPanel model){/**/}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not allowed to use lists in my project!

Comment: So like I posted, create 3 classes anyways it will be easy to handle and to maintain

Comment: @neto3 You don't need a list to do this, Maxim's point is just that if you have 3 near-identical items then creating a class for them is the most convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adverse to using a class, the other obvious way is to use a factory-type method.

```
JComboBox createComboBoxFor(int rgb) {
    return new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
        Integer.toString(rgb, 16), // not sure what hex1 is
        (rgb >>> 16 & 0xFF) + ", " + (rgb >>> 8 & 0xFF) + ", " + (rgb & 0xFF)
    }));
}
```

Then you do

```
JComboBox panel1Box = createComboBoxFor(panel1.getBackground().getRGB());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the Panels into an array and then looped through the array instead of specifying the specific Panel eg Panel1, Panel2

Comment: That's good idea and i'm going to use it! But i'm curious if there is another more appropriate way to do this!

Comment: Not that I can think of, if you're thinking of concatenating strings to get the variable you want eg "Panel" + num theres nothing like that similar to what you could find in JS. And if there was it would be pretty painful compared to just using an array